# Field lookup with a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

Hi guys i've been trying to figure out this problem for an hour or two and it's got me stumped.

So basically I have 3 models, A,B,C, all linked together using foreign keys.

```
b = B.objects.filter(resident=request.user)
c = C.objects.filter(todays_treatment=medication,patient=b)
```

however `c` won't give me any values except for the results of the first object returned in query `b`. I understand this is due to `b` being returned as a queryset, but I don't understand how I should be using it then? How can I get `c` to be the results for ALL of the objects in query `b`? How do you guys normally "follow" foreign key relationships? I've tried that `select_related()` function but it won't do what I want it to do. Please help!!

Comment: hey yes i will go on IRC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `__in` syntax:

```
c = C.objects.filter(todays_treatment=medication, patient__in=b)
```

To get all C objects where the patient is in the `b` queryset, assuming B objects are what `C.patient` points to.

Comment: thanks for replying so fast! can you tell me what __in does exactly? The docs are a bit vague..

Comment: It looks for results where the attribute is in the list provided to it.

Comment: It performs an SQL IN clause. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in